# Restrict Map Services available to a custom ArcGIS Server Print Service

Tags: arcgis-server, printing

I am setting up a custom print service in ArcGIS Server to use our own templates, but as this print service will run as the ArcGIS Server account it will potentially have access to all secured services.

**How can I restrict/white list the map services an ArcGIS Server Print Service will have access to?**

I do not wish to restrict access to the print service, it is to be publicly available, however I only want it to be available to print/export other public map services.

I can't see anything in [the documentation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-additional-services-for-printing.htm), however could possibly setup some form of [request filtering](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering) in IIS.

Comment: I believe you will not be able to restrict the access to the maps. You will only be able to [restrict users](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/restricting-access-to-gis-web-services.htm) based on your services directory.